# Angular services - multiple queries and summing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, ajax

I have 1 API/projects that returns a JSON with

```
[  
   {  
      "id":100,
      "name":"some name",
      "x": "y"
   },
   {  
      "id":200,
      "another name",
      "x": "z"
   }
]
```

I then have another API/costs call that returns something similar to:

```
[  
   {  
      "projectid":100,
      "cost":300
   },
   {  
      "projectid":100,
      "cost":100
   },
   {  
      "projectid":200,
      "cost":500
   }
]
```

I currently wrote a mess of ajax/jquery/JS code that builds a JS object with "id", "name", and the summed "cost". And I simply stringify it to a JSON object.

However, the following queries were more complex and it seemed like an inefficient and near impossible way to do through raw JS so I switched to angular services as it would be easier to inject for the front-end team.

I'm not familiar with angular at all, and I only have a simple service that queries all the projects or 1 project given the ID.

Is it possible in Angular to query the API and build a JSON that takes only the *name* and *id* from the first query, and sums the *cost* for the appropriate project in the second query and returns a JSON with:

```
[  
   {  
      "id":100,
      "name":"some name",
      "cost":400
   }
]
[  
   {  
      "id":200,
      "name":"another name",
      "cost":200
   }
]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some pseudo-code:

```
var projects = null;
$http.get('API/projects').then(function(response) {
        projects = JSON.parse(response.data);
        $http.get('API/costs').then(function(response) {
            var costs = JSON.parse(response.data);
            projects.forEach(function(project) {
                var sum = 0;
                costs.forEach(function(cost) {
                    if (project.id === cost.projectid) {
                        sum += cost.cost;
                    }
                });
                project.cost = sum;
            });
        };
    });
console.log(projects);
```

Should work with some tweaking.
Could be much more elegant though...

Comment: I am receiving "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at new <anonymous> " which to my understanding has something to do with no return in the function $http in the function? Does it have to have a return?

Comment: Nevermind, figured it out. Thank you this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

This is a solution with plain Javascript and linear complexity.

```js
var project = [{ "id": 100, "name": "some name", "x": "y" }, { "id": 200, name: "another name", "x": "z" }],
    cost = [{ "projectid": 100, "cost": 300 }, { "projectid": 100, "cost": 100 }, { "projectid": 200, "cost": 500 }],
    merged = function (p, c) {
        var o = {},
            r = p.map(function (a) {
                o[a.id] = { id: a.id, name: a.name, cost: 0 };
                return o[a.id];
            });
        c.forEach(function (a) {
            o[a.projectid].cost += a.cost;
        });
        return r;
    }(project, cost);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(merged, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```